# Ruby on Rails: routing problem: action is not seen in link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Just trying to set up some basic links with authlogic.
here they are

```
<% if current_user %>
    <div class="register_new_user">
        <%= link_to "Register", new_user_path %>
    </div>
    <div class="login_existing_user">
        <%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path %>
    </div>

<% else %>
    <div class="logout">
        <%= link_to "Log Out", :controller => :user_sessions, :action => :destroy %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

what is also weird is that `destroy_user_session_path` doesn't exist, and is what I would prefer to use.  But when I click the Logout Link, it just takes me to `localhost:3000/user_sessions/`

here is my user_sessions controller:

```
class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_no_user, :only => [:new, :create]
  before_filter :require_user, :only => :destroy

  def new
    @user_session = UserSession.new
  end

  def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
    if @user_session.save
      flash[:notice] = "Login successful!"
      redirect_back_or_default account_url
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    current_user_session.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Logout successful!"
    redirect_back_or_default new_user_session_url
  end
end
```

so, I'm confused as to why `new_user_session_path` works, and `destroy_user_session_path` doesn't.

for reference: my routes:

```
  map.resource :user_session
  map.resource :account, :controller => "users"
  map.resources :users

  map.root :controller => "info", :action => "home"
  map.connect "/home", :controller => "info", :action => "home"
```

Comment: can you give us a `rake routes` output.  Also, your if/else is backwards in the view:  if current user, you want them to be able to log out, else, signup/login

Comment: None of that affects your problem however, Jaime's answer is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this in your view:

```
<%= link_to "Log Out", user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

The reason you can't just have a `destroy_user_session_path` method is because that would be a GET request, which breaks RESTful routing convention.  GET requests are only meant to retrieve data, not create, update, or destroy it.

This should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

For UPDATE and DELETE you need to provide the method as a parameter:

```
<%= link_to "Log Out", user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use instead:

```
<%= link_to "Log Out", :controller => :user_session, :action => :destroy %>
```

Notice the controller in singular...

Comment: This won't work, it's still sending a GET request to an action that only responds to a DELETE request.