# Logout session is not working and throwing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I was trying to implement a logout option in my rails app.
To implement it, I followed [this SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044315/ruby-on-rails-routing-problem-action-is-not-seen-in-link-to). But I am getting errors.

[image]

Why is this occuring?

My routes for this controller

```
       login GET    /login(.:format)             sessions#new
    sessions GET    /sessions(.:format)          sessions#index
             POST   /sessions(.:format)          sessions#create
 new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)      sessions#new
edit_session GET    /sessions/:id/edit(.:format) sessions#edit
     session GET    /sessions/:id(.:format)      sessions#show
             PATCH  /sessions/:id(.:format)      sessions#update
             PUT    /sessions/:id(.:format)      sessions#update
             DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)      sessions#destroy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try: `<%= link_to 'Log Out', session_path(current_user), :method => :delete %>`

The `session_path` method takes a parameter which determines the id of the User object.  Also be sure to use `<%=` when you want to render the line instead of `<%`